# Kivy Splash Screen image with fade in effect

Tags: kivy, splash-screen

I would like to know how to make a splash screen with kivy and display a picture in fade in for few seconds.

The best i can do was with this code:

```py
class MyApp(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.splash_screen_image = Image(source='images/pyrat_icon.png', size=(0, 0))
        Clock.schedule_once(self.start_anim, .01)

    def build(self):
        self.main_widget = MainWidget()
        return self.main_widget

    def start_anim(self, dt):
        self.splash_screen_image.pos = (self.main_widget.center_x, self.main_widget.center_y)
        self.main_widget.add_widget(self.splash_screen_image)
        animation = Animation(x=self.main_widget.center_x - 35, y=self.main_widget.center_y - 35, height=70, width=70, d=2,
                              t='in_quad')
        animation.start(self.splash_screen_image)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.end_anim, 3)

    def end_anim(self, dt):
        self.main_widget.remove_widget(self.splash_screen_image)
```

This display my logo on the screen and it disappear after 3 seconds but it wait for the app to start so when the app is loading there is only a black window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Android/iOS:**

Splashscreen is used by default on python-for-android ([presplash](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/old_toolchain/toolchain/#step-2-package-your-application)), there you can set whatever image you like. Don't know how does it work on ios, but I think there is splashscreen too.

**Windows/Linux/Mac/RPi:**

No such thing exists on these. Maybe you can set something with [PyInstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) when packaging for the OS, otherwise you'd need to make it yourself. I can recommend you using [`ScreenManager`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) and its `Transitions` combined with [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) or maybe even [`Animation`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.animation.html) - depends on what wou want that image to do. [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fFfZ3ImgnI)

To set a length of a transition look [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py#L325), which should be accessible within transitions e.g. `FadeTransition(duration=1.5)`

Comment: Ok that's what I thought :/ I have added my code that zoom to my logo application for 3 seconds and disappear. I let the question open if one day kivy allow us to make a real splash screen.
Thank you.