# How to make an animated splash screen for android app using kivy?

Tags: android, python, kivy, splash-screen, animated-gif

I'm new to Python and kivy, just started creating an Android app.

I made a gif and I'm trying to make it work as the splash screen for my app using kivy and buildozer. The thing is that I've already tried everything I could find on google and nothing seems to work.

My first guess was to try it as a .gif image. The app loads only the first frame as if it was a static image. Then I tried to zip all the images and to point to the .zip file. It didn't even loaded. I even tried an animated png. Again, only the first frame is loaded. I don't know what else I can try...

The only place I'm referring to the file I want to use is in the buildozer.spec. Like this:

```
# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.gif
```

Do I need to write something on main.py or .kv files?

I'm using kivy 1.10.0, python 3.6.2, and buildozer 0.34dev, on linux manjaro.
Apart from this issue, the rest of the app works just as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kivy Splash Screen image with fade in effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165912/kivy-splash-screen-image-with-fade-in-effect)

Comment: My question is android specific. That guy is trying a different thing, on a desktop/laptop probably...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python-for-android displays the presplash image using an ImageView (see [here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/bootstraps/sdl2/build/src/org/kivy/android/PythonActivity.java#L424)). I don't think this supports gif animation. It should be possible to add animation, but only by changing this java code manually, there isn't any support for doing it automatically.